# How can I get the exact real solution of this equation?

Tags: equation-solving

I want to solve the equation

```
Sqrt[x] + Sqrt[1 - x^2] == Sqrt[2 - 3 x - 4 x^2]
```

with real solutions (in the real domain).
I tried

```
Solve[ Sqrt[x] + Sqrt[1 - x^2] == Sqrt[2 - 3 x - 4 x^2], Reals]
```

> ```
> {{x -> Root[-1 + 10 #1^2 + 9 #1^4 &, 2]^2}}
> ```

and also

```
Reduce[ Sqrt[x] + Sqrt[1 - x^2] == Sqrt[2 - 3 x - 4 x^2] && x ∈ Reals, x, Complexes]
```

> ```
> x == -1 - Sqrt[2] || x == 1/9 (-5 + Sqrt[34])
> ```

The real solution of the given equation is `x == 1/9 (-5 + Sqrt[34])`

With *Maple* I got

[image]

Comment: Isn't `-1 - Sqrt[2]` Real anymore?

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean. I am getting the correct answer (you mentioned) using both methods Solve and Reduce.

Comment: @belisarius and @Algohi, with `-1 - Sqrt[2]`, the `Sqrt[-1 - Sqrt[2]]`is not identified.

Comment: You can use `ToRadicals` to get `Root` expressions in terms of radicals.

Comment: @MichaelE2 The question asks how we should find all real solutions of the equation but the post incorectly says that there is only one solution.

Comment: @Artes I think the OP wants the one solution that makes all the square-roots in the equation real, but I may be wrong.  I also thinks he wants the answer `Solve` gives converted to the form `1/9 (-5 + Sqrt[34])`, which is why I left my comment.  I must admit I'm not sure I'm right, but it's my best guess.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I've explained that his claim, that there is one solution is wrong, there are two real solutions.

Comment: @Artes With Maple, I received one real solution. For me, the given equation has only one real solution.

Comment: @Artes I think the question, taken together with the OP's comments, is not clear, but your answer is and covers both interpretations, including the one in which the "solution of the equation with functions which are real" is sought.  As I'm typing this, it seems the OP is trying to clarify.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I use `Solve[Sqrt[x] + Sqrt[1 - x^2] == Sqrt[2 - 3 x - 4 x^2], x, Reals] // ToRadicals` and received one real solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**There are two real solutions, not only one as the question suggests**:

[image]

*Maple* is not an ultimate oracle, we have to understand what the solution is. 
It can be easily verified substituting solutions to the equation:

```
FullSimplify[ Sqrt[x] + Sqrt[1 - x^2] == Sqrt[2 - 3 x - 4 x^2] /. 
               { {x -> -1 - Sqrt[2]}, {x -> 1/9 (-5 + Sqrt[34])} }]
```

Any ambiguities should disappear taking a look at the documentation page of `Solve`, it says:

> ```
> Solve[ expr && vars ∈ Reals, vars, Complexes] solves for real values of variables, 
> but function values are allowed to be complex.
> ```

Analogous details one can find checking the `Reduce` page.
When we don't specify the domain, then by default it is assumed to be `Complexes` but as the documentation says the underlying functions may become complex but the condition  `x ∈ Reals` chooses only the real solutions

```
Solve[ Sqrt[x] + Sqrt[1 - x^2] == Sqrt[2 - 3 x - 4 x^2] && x ∈ Reals, x]
```

> ```
>  {{x -> -1 - Sqrt[2]}, {x -> 1/9 (-5 + Sqrt[34])}}
> ```

It yields in our case the same result when the domain is complex:

```
 Solve[ Sqrt[x] + Sqrt[1 - x^2] == Sqrt[2 - 3 x - 4 x^2] , x]
```

However when the real domain is chosen, it yields only

```
Solve[ Sqrt[x] + Sqrt[1 - x^2] == Sqrt[2 - 3 x - 4 x^2], x, Reals]
```

> ```
> {{x -> Root[-1 + 10 #1^2 + 9 #1^4 &, 2]^2}}
> ```

returns only that solution of the equation with functions which are real, with `ToRadicals` we can find that `{{x -> 1/9 (-5 + Sqrt[34])}}`.

**Warning:** *Mathematica 7* yields **the both solutions** in terms of radicals, while versions *8* and *9* return **only the one solution** `x -> Root[-1 + 10 #1^2 + 9 #1^4 &, 2]^2` in terms of the `Root` object. So the concept of solution with the domain specification has been changed since the version *8*, (the docs have been changed as well).

Compare:

```
FullSimplify[ Sqrt[2 - 3 x - 4 x^2] /. x -> 1/9 (-5 + Sqrt[34])]
```

> ```
> 1/9 Sqrt[61 + 13 Sqrt[34]]
> ```

while with the first solution the underlying function (`Sqrt[2 - 3 x - 4 x^2]`) simplifies to a complex number.

```
FullSimplify[ Sqrt[2 - 3 x - 4 x^2] /. x -> -1 - Sqrt[2]]
```

> ```
> I Sqrt[7 + 5 Sqrt[2]]
> ```

To conclude: in general to get all real solutions of the equation one should solve it this way:

```
Solve[ Sqrt[x] + Sqrt[1 - x^2] == Sqrt[2 - 3 x - 4 x^2] && x ∈ Reals, x]
```

because as we showed above **the first solution is ruled out by** the condition that **the function is not real**.

Comment: I used `Solve[Sqrt[x] + Sqrt[1 - x^2] == Sqrt[2 - 3 x - 4 x^2], x, Reals] // ToRadicals`, then I got one real solution.

Comment: I have just online. Thank you four your answer.

Comment: @minthao_2011 I expect you've understood my answer so I'm glad I could help a bit. In case you find something unclear try to expose the problem more clearly in your question. I find there might be some misleading issues, however I think recent updates of `Solve` are quite reasonable and in general it works better than formerly.

Comment: Perhaps about my English, therefore my question is not clearly. My question is "How many solutions when I solve the equation `Sqrt[x] + Sqrt[1 - x^2] == Sqrt[2 - 3 x - 4 x^2]` in the real domain?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers and your helps.

Comment: @minthao_2011 In general for transcendental equations it might be difficult to decide how many solutions there are, however in our case the equation appears to have two solutions regardless if we search for them in reals or in complexes.

Comment: I am a teacher. When I teach for my students, in this case, when we solve by hand, we always conclude the given solution has only real solution (solve in real domain). Am I wrong?

Comment: @minthao_2011 I don't think so, certain simple polynomial equations have also complex solutions (if coefficients are real there are conjugate pairs of solutions), thus you should specify what kind of equations you consider and then you have to check carefully all solutions. But as far as an equation is equivalent to a polynomial one the problem simplifies cosiderably.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15284/discussion-between-minthao-2011-and-artes).

Answer (score 4):

I post this only for insights into solving this equation (given the discussion) and ambiguity of interpretation...and for fun. I have alread +1 Artes answer.

```
f[x_] := Sqrt[x] + Sqrt[1 - x^2];
g[x_] := Sqrt[2 - 3 x - 4 x^2];
```

Note the domain that f(x)-g(x) is real valued.

```
dom = Reduce[x > 0 && Abs[x] < 1 && 2 - 3 x - 4 x^2 > 0]
```

is: 0 < x < 1/8 (-3 + Sqrt[41])

So if we only consider this domain:

```
Plot[f[x] - g[x], {x, -1, 1}, 
 GridLines -> {{dom[[1]], dom[[5]]}, None}, 
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[{Red, Thick}]]
```

[image]

The solution x= 1/9 (-5 + Sqrt[34]) is evident.

Regarding f and g as complex valued functions:

```
sol = Solve[
  Sqrt[x] + Sqrt[1 - x^2] == Sqrt[2 - 3 x - 4 x^2] && 
   x \[Element] Reals, x]
Show[Plot3D[{0, Abs[f[x + I y] - g[x + I y]]}, {x, -3, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
   MeshFunctions -> {#2 &, #3 &}, 
  Mesh -> {{0}, {0.0625, 0.125, 0.25, 0.5, 1}}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
  MeshStyle -> {Directive[Green, Thickness[0.01]], Red}], 
 Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[0.03], Point[{#, 0, 0} & /@ (x /. sol)]}]]
```

The zeroes on the real line are evident.

[image]

The "missing" solution  and the proof it is:

```
FullSimplify[g[-1 - Sqrt[2]]]
Simplify[f[-1 - Sqrt[2]]^2]
Simplify[g[-1 - Sqrt[2]]^2]
```

-> I Sqrt[7 + 5 Sqrt[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0pW0.gif)], -7 - 5 Sqrt[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0pW0.gif), -7 - 5 Sqrt[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0pW0.gif)

respectively.